# Copy functions back into objects parsed from a string

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have used JSON.stringy to convert a complex object to a string for saving, loading back in and parsing back to an object.

However, this will strip all of the functions from the original objects that were stringified then parsed.  I am aware that I can use Object.assign to create a new Object with the functions I want and then copy the properties from the parsed node into an object which has the needed functions.

```
myNode=Object.assign(new GrapNode(), parsedNode);
```

Whilst this works, myNode !=== parsedNode as they are different object instances. Is there elegant/cannonical a way to get all the GraphNode.prototype functions from the class GraphNode in to parsedNode without creating a new object.

Note* GraphNode is a class that I defined.

Comment: Doing `myNode=Object.assign(parsedNode, new GrapNode());` would keep the reference, but the values in `parsedNode` would probably be overwritten by GraphNode null values. I guess a solution would be to loop through GraphNode keys and assign the ones with type `function` to `parsedNode`. Not sure it elegant, but should work.

Comment: Are the functions directly in the `GrapNode()` object, or are they inherited from the prototype?

Comment: @Thiago Loddi But would that then mean every instance of GraphNode, for which there could be many, would each now have their own copies of the functions which is expensive and sluggish memory wise? When you make a class the instances get the functions from GraphNode.prototype.

Comment: @Barmar Inherited from the prototype I presume as I've used ES6 style classes to define the constructor, properties and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the prototype:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(parsedNode, GraphNode);
```

Comment: I'm trying this one out now.

Comment: Yep this one works. Thanks for letting me know about that function.  However, the warning on MDN webdocs is a little concerning.

Comment: This is the standard way of setting an object prototype as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), UP.

Comment: @AndrewS Don't worry about the warning unless you're doing this a lot in an inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe assign the methods from `GrapNode` manually to `parsedNode`

```
function copyNode(target, proto) {
  Object.keys(proto).forEach(k => {
    if(typeof proto[k] == 'function') {
      target[k] = proto[k];
    }
  });
}

copyNode(parsedNode, new GrepNode());
```

Comment: I'm giving you a point because I do believe this is another credible option and I want to thank you for replying.